# How to let CXF not respond after a timeout?

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, timeout, cxf

I'm exposing a SAOP Webservice via CXF and Apache Camel.

My client wants to NOT RECEIVE a response after 5 sec of the request.

How can I do it technically?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The client has to set a request timeout of 5 seconds.

Comment: There is a way to cut the communication? like killing the socket or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you do not need to do it by yourself. A timeout specifies the patience of the caller.

CXF has two timeouts, see the [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transports/http/configuration/HTTPClientPolicy.html) for more information:

- **connectionTimeout**: Specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that the consumer will attempt to establish a connection before it times out.
- **receiveTimeout**: Specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that the consumer will wait for a response before it times out.

In your case, the CXF client must set a `receiveTimeout` of `5000` (milliseconds). Perhaps you also want to customize the `connectionTimeout`. With the `receiveTimeout` set, the client sends a request against the server and if the server has not startet to send a response within 5 seconds, the client aborts the request.

I think you will get a `SocketTimeoutException` it the timeout occurs, but not sure about this.